# mod_perl How to return 511 status?

Tags: apache, perl, mod-perl

I am writing perl handler for Apache2.

This is my config:

```
PerlModule xxx::andsf 
<Location / >
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlHandler xxx::andsf
  PerlSendHeader On
</Location>
```

My handler need to return to client 511 HTTP Status code.
You can read about 511 here:

- http://www.askapache.com/net/http-status-odes.html#Network_Authentication_Required
- http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6585.html#status-511

if my code 
   return 505;
I receive correct status **505 HTTP Version not supported**.
But if I put
   return 511;
I get **500 - Internal server error.**
It seems Apache ignoring **strange** error code.

Any ideas how to return 511?

**Update** handler's code:

```
package xxx::andsf;
use Apache2::Const
  qw( :common );
use Apache2::RequestRec ();
use Apache2::RequestIO  ();

sub handler {
  my $r = shift;
  $r->status_line("511 Network Authentication Requred");
  return Apache2::Const::OK;
}
1;
```

Answer (score 2):

ModPerl 2?

You can use `$r->status_line("511 Network Authentication Requred")` and then return `Apache2::Const::OK` (0)

See: http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/Apache2/RequestRec.html#C_status_line_

Comment: Did it as u and article told. Now I am getting 200 OK with Content-type httpd/unix-directory

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue. 
It has nothing to do with ModPerl2 but Apache itself.
It is not a problem for Apache 2.4 only 2.2 affected.
After looking into Apache 2.2 source code and patching some lines to accept 511 (you can copy/paste those lines from source of Apache 2.4) it starts correctly to return code 511.